# Java: Accessibility problems with two methods in ArrayList (three classes)

Tags: java, methods

I have three classes: `Main`,`ReusaxCorp` and `Employee`. Let's get straight to the point: In the `ReusaxCorp` class I want to implement two methods: `retrieveEmployee`, which iterates through the Array List and **prints out all employees information**. So I tried this:

```
public void retrieveEmployee() {
    for (int i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("ID: " + employee.ID + END_OF_LINE + "Name: " + employee.name + END_OF_LINE + "salary: " + employee.grossSalary);
    }
}
```

**But that does not work, because I can't access - for instance - employee.ID or employee.name. In the second method.** `updateEmployee` **I would have liked to change the information, but that doesn't work either because of the accessibility.** I appreciate any kind of help. Here are my three classes:

```
public class Employee {

protected String ID;
protected String name;
protected double grossSalary;
final String END_OF_LINE = System.lineSeparator();

   public Employee (String ID, String name, double grossSalary){
       this.ID = ID;
       this.name = name;
       this.grossSalary = grossSalary;
   }

   public double getGrossSalary() {
       return grossSalary;
   }

   public void setGrossSalary(double grosssalary) {
       this.grossSalary = grossSalary;
   }

   public String getName(){
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
}
```

Here's my Main class:

```
public class Main {
private static String END_LINE;
private Scanner sc;
public String name;
public String ID;
public double salary;
private int GPA;
private ReusaxCorp reusaxcorp; 

public Main(){
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    END_LINE = System.lineSeparator();
}


   public void presentoptions(){
       while (true){
           System.out.println("=== Welcome === ");
           System.out.println("Choose an option below: ");
           System.out.println(" ");
           System.out.println("1. Register an employee. ");
           System.out.println("2. Remove an employee. ");
           System.out.println("3. Retrieve an employees information. ");

           int option = sc.nextInt();

           switch (option) {
               case 1:
                   System.out.println("What type of employee? " + END_LINE
                        + " - Intern. " + END_LINE
                        + " - Employee. " + END_LINE
                        + " - Manager. " + END_LINE
                        + " - Director." + END_LINE);
                   String type = sc.nextLine();

                   createEmployee();
                   break;

               case 2:
                   break;
               case 3:
                   reusaxcorp.retrieveEmployee();
                   break;
               default:
                   System.out.println("Error. Please try again.");
                   break;
           }
       }
   }

   public void createEmployee(){
       String typeofemployee = sc.nextLine();

           System.out.println("What's the ID of the new " + typeofemployee + "?");
           ID = sc.nextLine();
           System.out.println("What's the name of the new " + typeofemployee + "?");
           name = sc.nextLine();
           System.out.println("What's the salary of the new " + typeofemployee + "?");
           salary = sc.nextDouble();

           Employee employee = new Employee(ID, name, salary);

           switch (typeofemployee) {
               case "Intern":
                   System.out.println("What's the new Interns GPA? ");
                   GPA = sc.nextInt();                   
               case "Employee":
                   break;

               case "Manager":
                   break;

               case "Director":
                   break;

               default:
                   System.out.println("Error");
                   break;
           }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Main runcode = new Main();
       runcode.presentoptions();
   }
}
```

And here at last the `ReusaxCorp` class.

```
public class ReusaxCorp extends Main {

   ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
   final String END_OF_LINE = System.lineSeparator();

   public void registerEmployee(){
       employees.add(new Employee(ID, name, salary));
   }

   public void retrieveEmployee() {
       for (int i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++) {
           System.out.println("ID: " + employee.ID + END_OF_LINE + "Name: " + employee.name + END_OF_LINE + "salary: " + employee.grossSalary);
       }
   }

   public void updateEmployee(){
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the variable `employee` which does not exist anywhere int the class.

```
public void retrieveEmployee() {
   for (int i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++) {

       //add this line
       Employee employee = employees.get(i);

       System.out.println("ID: " + employee.ID + END_OF_LINE + "Name: " + employee.name + END_OF_LINE + "salary: " + employee.salary);
   }
}
```

You can also use a for-each loop:

```
for(Employee employee: employees){
    System.out.println("ID: " + employee.ID + END_OF_LINE + "Name: " + employee.name + END_OF_LINE + "salary: " + employee.salary);
}
```

Also note that accessing the fields such as `ID` using `employee.ID` is only applicable if the classes are in the same package (being protected). Otherwise you need to create a getter and access them using getter such as `employee.getID()`

Comment: @azurefrog noted and note added.

Comment: Thanks it's running, but I'm getting a NullPointerException. I don't know why though.

Comment: Where are you getting the NPE?

Comment: At reusaxcorp.retrieveEmployee(); It actually doesn't even execute the method retrieveEmploye(). Do you know where the mistake is?

Comment: Because you haven't initialized it. Use `private ReusaxCorp reusaxcorp = new ReusaxCorp();` instead of `private ReusaxCorp reusaxcorp;` in the main class.

Comment: Thanks but now it shows a Stackoverflow Error at public class ReusaxCorp extends Main

Comment: Your loop might be going to infinite loop, check it properly.

Comment: Even if I outcomment the for loop, an stackoverflow appears. It refers to private ReusaxCorp reusaxcorp = new ReusaxCorp();. Please help me

Comment: You have used `ReusaxCorp extends Main` and creating new object of `ReusaxCorp` in the constructor of  `Main` would definately lead to an infinite loop. Either do not extend `ReusaxCorp` from `Main` or leave `private ReusaxCorp reusaxcorp;` as it is and instantinate it just before while loop as `reusaxcorp = new ReusaxCorp();`

Answer (score 0):

Use `employee.getId()` instead of `employee.ID` while iterating through the list of employees, you already have those `public` getter methods implemented while the class members are `protected`. Do so for the other class members (name and so on) as well…
You can do that in your solution by getting the employee from the list by index like

```
System.out.println(employees.get(i).getId());
```

or you just take a "for each" loop like

```
for (Employee employee : employees) { 
    System.out.println(employee.getId()); 
}
```